# Not able to access the Word Document on my system using the UWP application

Tags: c#, uwp, openxml, windows-10-universal, openxml-sdk

I am trying to edit a existing Word document using the UWP app (Universal Windows). But for some reason I am getting "File does not exist" error.

I have tried using the below code to access the word document:

```
using(WordprocessingDocument wordDoc = WordprocessingDocument.Open("C:\\Users\\Public\\Desktop\\Doc1.docx", true))
{

}
```

System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 'Could not find document'

Comment: From the error, it really seems like the file doesn't exist under this path, watch out for typos

Comment: @YannThibodeau There are no typos. I checked the filepath 10s of time. I tried running the same code on Winforms app and it worked. This issue is only happening when i run it on UWP app.

Comment: @YannThibodeau Do UWP app have the capability to edit word documents?

Comment: Well, this seems to be an issue with UWP app, you should report this issue on their github probably.

Comment: UWP is sandboxed and therefor you cannot access the Desktop, Downloads, Documents etc by default. You have a few options however, you can include the word doc in your app and access it as you would access any resource. You can use a File Picker which will allow the user to manually select the Word Doc, thus giving your app permission to access the file. Or as @Xavier says, you can declare broadFileSystemAccess which will give your app the same permissions as the user. However, with this method it is fine for sideloading but you may have issues publishing on the store.

Comment: @AdamMcMahon Do you have an example/link where it explains how to do that? I can add the Word document but I am not sure how to access that document.

Comment: I'll write an answer based on your requirements. Which of the 3 options above is more suitable?

Comment: @AdamMcMahon Having the word doc on the app is suitable. (If possible instead of user manually selecting it, can you show how to select this automatically).

Comment: @XavierXie I added the broadFileSystemAcess to the Package Manifest file and the  and included the Windows.Storage namespace. Even so I encountered the error that the file was not found. I have opened an issue with OpenXml yesterday, I will add today's findings too. Thank you!

Comment: @AdamMcMahon After trying your code, I am getting "Access to the path is Denied" error. I am running this program on my local machine. Do I have to change anything on the program to provide access? Thank you for your inputs!

Comment: I'm going to install the same nuget package and test for myself, i'll report my findings when complete

Comment: Okay, I think the error was happening because UWP does not allow you to write files to the installation folder, just read from them. So I've edited my answer with an adjusted solution which appears to be working for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on further clarification in the comments section, please see the following instructions.

1. Add your .DOCX file to the Assets folder within your project and set the build action to "Content".

   [image: Set Build action to Content]
2. In order to write any changes to the file, we'll need to copy it to the packages `LocalFolder` and then access it from there.

   ```
   var file = await StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/doc1.docx"));
   if (file != null)
   {
       //Copy .docx file to LocalFolder so we can write to it
       await file.CopyAsync(ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder);
       String newFile = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path + "/doc1.docx";

       using (WordprocessingDocument wordDoc = WordprocessingDocument.Open(newFile, true))
       {
               //Your code here
       }
   }
   ```

You'll need to expand on this somewhat to make sure the file is only copied to the `LocalFolder` once etc, but you get the basic idea.

Comment: Thank you Adam, but now I am getting "Access to the path is Denied" error. I am running this program on my local machine. Do I have to change anything on the program to provide access?

Comment: Let me install the nuget package and test myself.

Comment: Okay, I think the error was happening because UWP does not allow you to write files to the installation folder, just read from them. So my adjusted solution is above.

Comment: Great. If you could consider accepting this as the correct answer so that it may help future users, that would be great. :)

Answer (score 0):

By default, the UWP doesn't allow to access the files outside the app container. But from windows 10 build 17134, a new capability `broadFileSystemAccess` has been introduced. It allows apps to get the same access to the file system as the user who is currently running the app without any additional file-picker style prompts during runtime.

So, please check if you have declare this capability in the 'Package.appxmanifest' file.

Please see [File access permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/file-access-permissions#accessing-additional-locations) and broadFileSystemAccess entry in [App capability declarations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/packaging/app-capability-declarations) for more information.

If you still face this issue when you add the `broadFileSystemAccess` capability, then, the issue should be in 'WordprocessingDocument.Open' API. You need to note that 'File access permissions' document has mentioned:

> This `broadFileSystemAccess` capability works for APIs in the [Windows.Storage](https://learn.microsoft.com/uwp/api/Windows.Storage) namespace.

This means that the 'WordprocessingDocument.Open' may not use the [Windows.Storage](https://learn.microsoft.com/uwp/api/Windows.Storage) APIs to access the files. If so, you need to report this issue to [Open-XML-SDK](https://github.com/OfficeDev/Open-XML-SDK/issues).