# Generate Doc file using OPEN-XML SDK in UWP

Tags: c#, uwp, openxml-sdk, wordprocessingml

I want to Create a Microsoft Word Document in my UWP App and I've successfully created doc file in APP Local folder. But i want to create this doc file in a specific folder location chosen by user.

> I mean user browse a location and then create doc file into that
>   location.

**Here is my code to create Doc file in App local Path:**

```
  string docFileName = "TestDoc.docx";
  Windows.Storage.StorageFolder localFolder = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;

  string Filepath = localFolder.Path + "\\" + docFileName;

  using (var wordprocessingDocument = WordprocessingDocument.Create(file.Path, DocumentFormat.OpenXml.WordprocessingDocumentType.Document))
  {
      MainDocumentPart mainPart = wordprocessingDocument.AddMainDocumentPart();
      mainPart.Document = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing.Document();
      Body body = mainPart.Document.AppendChild(new Body());
      DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing.Paragraph para = body.AppendChild(new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing.Paragraph());
      DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing.Run run = para.AppendChild(new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing.Run());
      run.AppendChild(new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing.Text("Hello !!! ."));
      wordprocessingDocument.MainDocumentPart.Document.Save();
  }
```

I've got below error while trying to create doc file in a specific location like below:

**Error**

> Message=The media is write protected : 'D:\Training\TestDoc.docx'

**Code**

```
string path = @"D:\Training\TestDoc.docx";

using (var wordprocessingDocument = WordprocessingDocument.Create(path, DocumentFormat.OpenXml.WordprocessingDocumentType.Document))
{
    MainDocumentPart mainPart = wordprocessingDocument.AddMainDocumentPart();
    mainPart.Document = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing.Document();
    Body body = mainPart.Document.AppendChild(new Body());
    DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing.Paragraph para = body.AppendChild(new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing.Paragraph());
    DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing.Run run = para.AppendChild(new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing.Run());
    run.AppendChild(new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing.Text("Hello !!! ."));
    wordprocessingDocument.MainDocumentPart.Document.Save();
}
```

Comment: My answer to a similar question may be of help here > https://stackoverflow.com/a/56379231/7446765

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because UWP apps run in a sandbox, you cannot directly access filesystem paths using classic APIs. However, you can use `Windows.Storage` APIs to do so.

### Let user choose the save file

If you want to let the user choose the save file, you can use the `FileSavePicker` API. [This Docs page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/quickstart-save-a-file-with-a-picker) describes this in detail. Once done, the API will give you a `StorageFile` instance, which you can use.

### Write in the file

As you cannot use the `Create` method which takes a file path as an argument, you need to use the `Stream` based one instead.

To get a `Stream` instance from the file, add `using System.IO;` to the top of your code file and then do:

```
using(var stream = await file.OpenStreamForWriteAsync())
```

With this stream you can then do:

```
using (var wordprocessingDocument =
               WordprocessingDocument.Create(
                  stream, WordprocessingDocumentType.Document))
{
      //... your code
}
```

#### Note: Broad filesystem access

If you really need to create the file at an arbitrary (not user selected) location, you can use the [`broadFileSystemAccess` capability](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/file-access-permissions#accessing-additional-locations). This is however only for apps that really require it. Note, that even with this capability, you still need to perform all file operations using the `StorageFile` and `StorageFolder` APIs.

Comment: Some time ago, but can you please explain how to save the document created as a storage file.